# How to pass parameter/attribute to JSR-356 WebSocket client (@ClientEndpoint)?

Tags: java, websocket, jsr356

I want to add some additional attributes to container-instantiated WebSocket client endpoint for grouping/statistics. I created a client WebSocket endpoint with JSR-356:

`Session session = container.connectToServer( MyClientEndpoint.class , uri );`

I want to pass some object to `Session` or `MyClientEndpoint` instance:

```
@ClientEndpoint
public class MyClientEndpoint {

    @OnOpen
    public void onWebSocketConnect( Session sess ) {
       ...i need my param here...
    } 

    ... @OnMessage, @OnClose, @OnError handlers...
}
```

Because **`MyClientEndpoint` instance is instantiated by container** (in my example - Jetty), I cannot just pass argument in constructor. Also I cannot set my param in `Session` user properties:

`Session session = container.connectToServer( ClientSocket.class , uri );`
`session.getUserProperties().put( "group", this);`

because I don't have my property in `@OnOpen` handler and also I have no guarantee that my `"group"` property will be set **before any `@OnMessage` call**.

**How to connect to JSR-356 WebSocket in a way that will allow me to use additional objects in @ClientEndpoint object instantiated by container?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, we are not forced to container-instantiation of `@ClientEndpoint` instances. We can pass our custom instance:

```
ClientSocket socket = new ClientSocket( ANY PARAMS WE WANT );
Session session = container.connectToServer( socket , uri );
```

Comment: even if you want to use container instantiation, there is a way - you can add properties you need to pass to ClientEndpointConfig and the retrieve it in @OnOpen (it can be added as another parameter). See EndpointConfig.getUserProperties.